# Connect to remote unix server, sudo in, and run other dynamic commands in Java?

Tags: java, unix, user-interface, command-line

I was looking for a solution where(using a java GUI) I can log in to a remote unix server, "sudo su" in, and run other commands based on a user's input on the java GUI. Is there an easy way to do it with only the SDK(no external libraries) or are there external libraries that allow for sending single commands(as though you were in a shell) without the need to build a shell script?(I am trying to create a command-line GUI in java, and am wondering what approach I should take for the backend of this tool . . .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSCH http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ is used by Maven and is quite good